# Why on Jenkins multiconfiguration job with Android plugin failed?

Tags: java, android, testing, android-emulator, jenkins

> ...\Jenkins\workspace\AndroidTestCalculatorTest3\density\160\os\2.2\resolution\QVGA\build.xml:185:
>
> Cannot find
>   ...\android-sdks\tools\ant\build.xml
>   imported from
>
> ...\Jenkins\workspace\AndroidTestCalculatorTest3\density\160\os\2.2\resolution\QVGA\build.xml

What should I do to import this file/path on server that Jenkins won't have any problems?

Sometime I have timeout problem is there a way to change lenght of timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build file in your project can't find the parent Ant build file from the Android SDK.

In your "Execute Ant script" build step, under "Properties" under "Advanced..." you should add:

```
sdk.dir=$ANDROID_HOME
```

This assumes that either the ANDROID_HOME environment variable has already been set for the Jenkins user, or you're using the Android Emulator Plugin (which it looks like you are).

Comment: @Christopher is is possible to get to $ANDROID_HOME without having the emulator running?
I have some android builds that are just there to build. Adding the emulator to the mix increases the build time by minutes.

Comment: @copolii You can set it in your Jenkins slave's environment variables, or I believe using the "Install Android project prerequisites" build step should do that for you.